# Show only short part of link in comment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

if the user inserted the link into the comment, this link needs to be cut off to 20 characters.

How to make it?

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
```

It shall turn out so.

```
Lorem ipsum: https://github.com/plataforma...
```

Comment: Can you show your sample input and sample output.

Comment: @vee  
 The user enters the normal comment and if it entered the link which needs to be cut off.  
 For example:

  `Lorem ipsum: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise`

  It shall turn out so.
  
  `Lorem ipsum: https://github.com/plataforma...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output text that's truncated you can use the built in string functionality

```
<%= link[0..19] %>
```

If you want it as part of a link_to, but want the full link on navigation perhaps something like:

```
<%= link_to link[0..19], url_for(link) %>
```

Comment: I need to cut off the link if it is present at the comment.
For this purpose I think is necessary callback?

Answer (score 2):

From what end do you want to truncate?

Using `String#[]` you can get substrings from any end:

```
s = "string with more than twenty characters"
s[0, 20] # get the first 20 characters
=> "string with more tha"
s[s.size-20, s.size] # the last 20 characters
=> "an twenty characters"
```

Rails also adds the [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) method to String:

```
"string with more than twenty characters".truncate(20)
=> "string with more ..."
"string with more than twenty characters".truncate(20, omission: "")
=> "string with more tha"
```

Hope that helps.